# Set selected value as selected when choosing from msql dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, select

I started a php-course. Now I've "learned" how to display sql-data into a html-table. The following question is right now above my knowledge... but I am nevertheless interested to solve it, as it would help me. I found some solutions, but not in connection with mysql.

I have a mysql-view with three columns: Brewery, City and Beer.
I'd like to give the customer the possibility to choose the City from a dropdown. For this purpose I created a form action:

```
<?php $CityShow = 'All' ?>;

<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post' name='form_filter' >
    <h2>City</h2>
    <?php
    $resultSet = $Verbindung->query("SELECT DISTINCT City FROM breweries");
    ?>
    <select name = 'City'>
    <?php
       echo"<option selected value = $City>All</option>";
       while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
       {
          $City = $rows ['City'];
          echo"<option value = '{$City}'>{$City}</option>";
       };
    ?>
    <input type='submit' value = 'Send'>
    <!-- <?php $CityShow = $_POST["City"]; ?>; -->
  </select>
```

This works fine, the customer can choose the City and the table is built dynamically.

```
<?php
if($CityShow == '' || $CityShow == 'All'){
$SQL = "SELECT * from Breweries";
}
else{
  $SQL = "SELECT * from Breweries where city = '$CityShow'";   
}

$Ergebnis =  $Verbindung->query($SQL);
?>
<!-- fill table-->
<?php
if($Ergebnis->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><th>Brewery</th><th>City</th><th>Beer</th></tr>";
   while($row = $Ergebnis->fetch_assoc()){
   echo"<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Brewery'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['City'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['Beer'] . "</td>";
   echo"</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
 }
 ?>
```

I guess, that's not the best way, but it works for me.

My problem:
Currently, when a city is chosen with the submit button, the focus always changes back to 'All" (this is an option, which is not in the database - its purpose is to show all records). I'd like to keep the focus on the chosen City.

Yves

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Within the option tag where you would normally type in the static attribute `selected`, you enter a conditional that checks to see if the value is set and if it is setm then echo out the attribute `selected`.

Below is an example of a static select/option setting the set value to selected.

```
<select class="form-control" name="city">
    <option value="San Diego"<?php if($row['City'] === "San Diego"){ echo ' selected'; } ?>>San Diego</option>
    <option value="Austin"<?php if($row['City'] === "Austin"){ echo ' selected'; } ?>> Austin</option>
    <option value="New Orleans"<?php if($row['City'] === "New Orleans"){ echo ' selected'; } ?>>New Orleans</option>
    <option value="Portland"<?php if($row['City'] === "Portland"){ echo ' selected'; } ?>>Portland</option>
    <option value="Detroit"<?php if($row['City'] === "Detroit"){ echo ' selected'; } ?>>Detroit</option>                                    
</select>
```

If your select is created dynamically using an array of cities and you wish to loop over that array and find the set city that is set in your $row array you can iterate over the array and set a conditional that looks for the set value from the DB:

```
//start your select and assign to a variable
$stmt = '<select class="form-control" name="city">';
// Run the array of cities through a loop
foreach($breweries as $city){
    //if the value from DB $row['City'] is equal to a value in the array set selected in the  
    //option tag else we display without selected attribute in the option tag
    if($row['City'] === $city){
        $stmt .= '<option value="'.$city.'" selected>'.$city.'</option>';
    }else{
        $stmt .= '<option value="'.$city.'">'.$city.'</option>';
    }
}
//close the select tag
$stmt .= '</select>';
```

Comment: This is crying out for an array and a loop.